# how to wrap two Text elements in a same row

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have two `Text` elements like below,

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '75%'}}>
   <Text>This is the first Text to render which is so lengthy to render in a single line</Text>
   <Icons name={'dot'} /> 
   <Text>This is the second Text to render</Text>
</View>
```

output looks like below,

[image]

we can notice one thing here,

First `Text` is truncated and showing ellipsis. Can I assume that since there are two `Text` elements both are truncated after specified width and since second `Text` is beyond the Screen `Width`, we are unable to see it. Please correct If I am wrong

If the first `Text` is so lengthy to be truncated, I don't want `dot(.) Icon` and second `Text` to be rendered. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Try to do this hope it will help you :-)
```

<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '75%',flex:1 }}>

```
<View style={{ width: "100%", marginTop: 20 }}>
                            <View style={{ 
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        alignItems: 'flex-start',
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor:'yellow'

}}>
```

<Text style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}>This is the first Text
<Text style={{backgroundColor:"green" }}>This is the second Text to render

Comment: Your solution works well only when first Text is so lengthy. if the first `Text` is very short there will be some white space after it since it has `flex: 8`. And first text is Dynamic(Can be short or long). is it possible to handle this scenario?

Comment: still same issue. please have a look at the screen shot in updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can add logic to it

1. Find the view length
2. Find the first text length
3. Find the second text length
   Now compare the view length and sum of both text length
   If view length is less then sum of text length hide the second text

To find the view length use "onLayout" property

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/honest-donut

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { View, Text } from "react-native";

var ViewWidth=0;
var FirstTextViewWidth=0;
var SecondTextViewWidth=0;

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      secondTextVisible:true
    }}

   

  render() {
    return (
      <View  style={{flex: 1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
      <Text>THis is problem</Text>
      
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', width: '75%', marginTop:10}}>
        <Text>This is the first Text to render which is so lengthy to render in a single line</Text>
        <Text>.</Text>
        <Text>This is the second Text to render</Text>
      </View>

      <Text>THis is solution</Text>
      <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', marginTop:10}} onLayout={(event) => {
          
          ViewWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width
        }}>
        <Text  onLayout={(event) => {
          var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
          
          FirstTextViewWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width
          
        }}>First text is lengthy so hide second text as its length is big</Text>
        <Text>.</Text>
        
        {this.state.secondTextVisible?
        <Text  onLayout={(event) => {
          SecondTextViewWidth = event.nativeEvent.layout.width
          /*20 here is substracted for padding*/
          if((ViewWidth-20)<(FirstTextViewWidth+SecondTextViewWidth)){
              this.setState({ 
              secondTextVisible:false  
            },()=>{console.log('>>>>>')}) 
          }
         
        }}>This is the second Text to render</Text> 
        :null
        }
        
      </View>
           
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: if I give `flexWrap: "wrap"` last item will come to next line which i don't want to be happened. I want to have all  items in single line

Comment: Updated the example. Hope this help.

Comment: `View's` `onLayout` is being called. but `Text's` `onLayout` is never called. what should i do?